# How to specify f-bounded polymorphism in python typing ( i.e. refering to the type of a subclass )

Tags: python, mypy, typing, f-bounded-polymorphism

An simple example of what I want to achieve:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic
from abc import abstractmethod

T = TypeVar( "T", bound="Copyable['T']" )

class Copyable( Generic[T] ):
    @abstractmethod
    def Copy( self ) -> T:
        pass

class Example( Copyable[ 'Example' ] ):
    def Copy( self ) -> 'Example':
        return Example()
```

However,

Pylance complains with: `TypeVar bound type cannot be generic`

MyPy complains with: `error: Type variable "script.example.T" is unbound`

Any ideas of how I could achieve this.

**Extra details**

The following is not a solution as it removes information. After copying an object of type `Example` its type would be reduced to `Copyable`.

```py
class Copyable:
    @abstractmethod
    def Copy( self ) -> Copyable:
        pass

class Example( Copyable ):
    def Copy( self ) -> Copyable:
        return Example()
```

**Context**

I would like to use this for a class which takes callbacks who's first argument is the class it was given to.
This class can be subclassed, meaning if the callback is of the type `Callback[ [ Baseclass ], None ]` then it will not have access ( without casting ) to methods of the derived class.

Comment: Note that you seem to have a misunderstanding of what `bound` means in the `TypeVar`: it means that for all valid types `cls` that can meant with `T`, `issubclass(cls, bound)` is true. Therefore the bound `Copyable[T]` is complete nonsense. It would say `issubclass(T, Copyable[T])` is true, which is an infinitely recursive type.

Comment: This is what f-bounded polymorphism is ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification )

Comment: You might be using the term f-bounded polymorphism correctly, but that isn't what Python's `TypeVar`'s `bound` parameter does. Python only implements Bounded Polymorphism.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is the `Self` type - this describes a method that returns the type of the class in it's current state (even if it goes through multiple inheritance):

```py
from typing import Self
from abc import abstractmethod, ABC

class Copyable(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def Copy(self) -> Self:
        ...

class Example(Copyable):
    def Copy(self) -> Self:
        return self.__class__()
```

### Via classmethod

Depending on the use case, you might also be able to implement Copy as a class method, to avoid using `self.__class__`.

```py
from typing import Self
from abc import abstractmethod, ABC

class Copyable(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    @classmethod
    def Copy(cls) -> Self:
        ...

class Example(Copyable):
    @classmethod
    def Copy(cls) -> Self:
        return cls()
```